# Add PlayerId to Meteor.user using oneSignal

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts, onesignal

I am trying to use [one Signal](https://onesignal.com/) to send push notifications to my users when they place and order, and when the order changes. How can I associate the Player ID from one Signal to the Meteor user?

So I can use the following Meteor method?

```js
Meteor.methods({
  finishOrder: function(id) {
    var data;
    var PlayerId = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:id}).playerId
    data = {
      contents: {
        en: 'We are reviewing the order'
      }
    };
    return OneSignal.Notifications.create([PlayerId], data);
  }
});
```

I think it has something to do with

```js
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
  console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
  alert("userId = " + ids.userId + ", pushToken = " + ids.pushToken);
});
```

```js
var userVar = new ReactiveVar(null);


if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 6, visualLevel: 4});
    window.plugins.OneSignal
      .startInit('------')
      .getIds(function(ids) {
        userVar.set(ids.userId)
      .endInit();
      }, false);
  });
  Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    return window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
      return Meteor.users.update({
        _id: Meteor.userId()
      }, {
        $set: {
          playerId: userVar.get()
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

But I cannot get it to work. Because it would run and wouldnt get a Meteor user, because it hasnt signed in.

Comment: Make sure `OneSignal.getIds` isn't being called before `.endItit()` is called. Also note that `OneSignal.getIds` does not return a value and the function passed to it does not do anything with the a returned value from it. Not sure if you are depending on this.

Comment: @jkasten if the OneSignal.getIds doesnt return a value then how would I assign a player Id to a Meteor.user? This is so that only the user gets notified when the order changes?   what does https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--getids- do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer, it was quite simple.
 First of as meteor as cordova and using a reactive var you assign the player Id to the userVar (reactive Var)

```js
var userVar = new ReactiveVar(null);


if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 5, visualLevel: 4});
    window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit('-------')
    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
      userVar.set(ids.userId);
    });
    window.plugins.OneSignal.endInit();
      }, false);
  Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    Meteor.call('addPlayerId', userVar.get())
  });

}
```

Then using a Meteor Method established in the server

```js
Meteor.methods({
  addPlayerId: function(playerId) {
    return Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    }, {
      $set: {
        playerId: playerId
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Finally this last part.

```js
  Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    Meteor.call('addPlayerId', userVar.get())
  });
```